# How to query positive value as negative in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my query - and i want the value of B which is positive to query as negative. So that i can sum them group by hole_depth

```
SELECT 
class,
start_time,
end_time,
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time))) AS time_diff,
hole_depth

FROM
(SELECT "A" AS class, TIME("2020-10-01 01:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-01 02:00:00") AS end_time, 1000 AS hole_depth
UNION
SELECT "B" AS class, TIME("2020-10-01 02:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-01 08:00:00") AS end_time, 1000 AS hole_depth
UNION
SELECT "A" AS class, TIME("2020-10-01 10:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-01 15:00:00") AS end_time, 2000 AS hole_depth
UNION
SELECT "B" AS class, TIME("2020-10-01 16:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-01 20:00:00") AS end_time, 2000 AS hole_depth
UNION 
SELECT "B" AS class, TIME("2020-10-01 20:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-01 23:00:00") AS end_time, 2000 AS hole_depth
UNION
SELECT "C" AS class, TIME("2020-10-02 01:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-02 3:00:00") AS end_time, 2000 AS hole_depth
UNION
SELECT "C" AS class, TIME("2020-10-02 03:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-02 4:00:00") AS end_time, 2000 AS hole_depth
UNION
SELECT "A" AS class, TIME("2020-10-02 04:00:00") AS start_time, TIME("2020-10-02 07:00:00") AS end_time, 2000 AS hole_depth
) t

GROUP BY hole_depth, class
```

---

The result

[image]

Expected Result

All value of B must return negative value. i.e. -21600, -25200

Comment: Instead of selecting `hole_depth`, select `-1 * hole_depth`?

Comment: `CASE WHEN class = B THEN -hole_depth ELSE hole_depth As hole_depth`?

Comment: @kmoser your answer is brilliant thx ...simplicity to the point

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thx your answer complements kmoser answer you are the best thx